# No static files when DEBUG is False

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I've some problem with deployment my application to production server. If I've set in settings.py

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
```

then everything works ok, but if I change settings to:

```
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
```

then my app is broken. I don't see static files (js, css, ...) and in admin panel I'm not able to add/edit my registered models.
Do you have any advices how can I resolve this issue?

My envoirment:

- Python 2.7.3
- Django 1.4.1
- Nginx 1.2.3
- uwsgi 1.3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should read: [Serving static files in production.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-production)

At least it sounds like you are relying on the helper view `staticfiles_urlpatterns()` from contrib.staticfiles which is only intended for development:

> This will only work if DEBUG is True.
>
> That's because this view is grossly inefficient and probably insecure.
>   This is only intended for local development, and should never be used
>   in production.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. After changes my main site loads all static files correctly, but still I have some problem with admin panel. In case when I have disabled DEBUG mode, then my registered models in admin site don't work properly. I see the model names, but actions add/edit aren't visible. Do you have any idea how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I guess it has to do with your `STATIC_ROOT` and `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` settings. Did you read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/releases/1.4/#django-contrib-admin?

Comment: I saw this document, but it looks that it's not a reason. I try to ask another question to this issue. Once again thanks for you advice with static files.

Answer (score 1):

Mee too had this problem, i solved it.

Just try

in settings.py

```
DEBUG = False
```

then add

```
DEBUG404 = True 
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] # it works but not secure, so use

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', 'IP adrs'] #if you are running locally, then run with python manage.py runserver --insecure.You can give your webserver here.
```

Then in urls.py add

```
import os
if settings.DEBUG404:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')} ),
    )
```